# Can not checkout to different branch after renaming directories with capitalization

Tags: git

I had to rename some of my directories from 'logo' 'color' to 'Logo' 'Color'.

I did this rename with the below commands.

```
git mv logo tmp
git mv tmp Logo
```

This was done in a separate branch.
Hence the branch structure is like this:

```
-- main --- feature/something
      \
       \
         ---- rename/logo-to-Logo
```

I am currently on the `rename/logo-to-Logo` branch, and the following error happens
when I try to checkout to any other branch.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    logo/somethingfile.txt
    logo/someotherfile.ts
    logo/allotherfiles.css
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's seems than these files are not added and comited.

Did you used `git add` before comit ?

Comment: No there is nothing to add. No changes at this point. Everything is committed

Comment: what you have when you do `git status` ?

Comment: None. Nothing at all. I’m thinking I might have to `git checkout —force`?

Comment: I’m on macOS. Yeah that is exactly the problem I’m trying to fix. Making a case sensitive change to the directory name on a case insensitive filesystem...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it.
It's because when you renamed directories, you didn't removed old directories with files inside.

You are using `Logo` as directory, not `logo` right ?

So you just have to delete this directory and files inside.

Comment: But how can I delete the `logo` directory in the other branch, if I can’t checkout to it?

Comment: You have an error because files still exist in your `rename/logo-to-Logo` branch.

Delete it, checkout, and you will have files again in your directory if there are in the other branch.

Comment: You can also save it somewhere to avoid some mistake

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly what I thought. But my `rename/logo-to-Logo` branch actually doesn’t have the `logo` directory files. They were moved to `Logo`.

Comment: if you look the directory where you have files, the logo directory doesn't exist ?

Anyway, another option it's to force the checkout, it will solve your problem too

Comment: Thanks for following through with me. I think the core problem is that I didn't change git config to be case sensitive (I didn't do this because my co-workers would have the same local setting). So git can't differentiate between the `logo` directory and the `Logo` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I set
`git config core.ignorecase true`

Then, the above checkout error is gone.

I still don't understand why this error takes place when
`core.ignorecase` is set to false.